# Cannot install PowerShell 2 on my Vista x64 machine

Tags: powershell

Help!

I'm trying to install PowerShell 2 on my main machine. Its running Vista x64 Home Premium. I'm running on an account with admin privileges.

I've tried asking this question on Super User, but no answers to date.

Here's what I've done so far:

- Downloaded the Windows Management Framework core package
- Run the install
- Got the message: "The update does not apply to your system"
- Googled the problem and found out that I had to uninstall PowerShell 1 first
- Uninstalled PowerShell 1 and re-booted.
- Re-run the WMF installer, and get "The update does not apply to your system"
- Google some more with no-so-useful results
- Ask question on ServerFault, no replies/answers

Which brings me to here. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

I should also add that I have *not* installed Vista x64 SP1 on my system. Automatic updates tried to install SP1 but failed with no specific error message. Since my system works without SP1, and I'm waiting for my next machine (which will run Win7), I don't particularly feel inclined to install SP1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Powershell 2.0 and associated components need at least SP1 on Vista. You should really run SP2 though, there are a ton of improvements.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968929

Comment: Fine!! I'll try to upgrade to SP2. Thanks for the info.

Nice error message, eh?

Comment: Also ensure you have the right installer, there are several depending on target OS and processor architecture.